# jQuery Hover to Change Another Element on the Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, coda-slider

I am new to jQuery and trying to create an interactive slider on Wordpress that does two things:

1)On hover, it displays a new div in the main photo box

2)On click of the link, it takes you to that page

However, the error console is telling me that next is not defined later in the script.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function slideShow() {
            var current = jQuery('#featArea.show');
        var next = jQuery('#defaultImg');

        $('div#featLinkWorkshop a').hover (
            function() {
                next = jQuery('div#featWorkshops');
            }

//repeat the above for each section

    current.removeClass('show');
        next.fadeIn().addClass('show');

        setTimeout(slideShow, 3000);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="defaultImg" class="featImg show">
    <img src="#" />
</div>

<div id="featWorkshops" class="featImg">
    <img src="#" />
<div class="featImgCaption">

    <h1>Caption Title</h1>
    <p>Sentence of interest.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then Later in the HTML

```
<div class="featLink" id="featLinkWorkshop">
    <img src="#" />

    <a href="#">Workshops</a>
</div>
```

Here is the page that you can view it on: http://www.toppling-dominoes.com/sevenoaks.
Thank you so much!

UPDATE: I have gotten the slider nearly functioning with the help of wahtever's ideas and [this tutorial](http://www.drselkirk.com/sneazy-blog/2011/6/22/jquery-cycle-demo-w-custom-thumbnail-navigation-and-live-tex.html). The cycle plugin has a lot more to it than I initially thought.

Comment: what this do ?    next = jQuery('div#featWorkshops');

Comment: I am trying to make next the ID of the div I would like to make visible.

Comment: you can give all those div an id and use show() hide() in a loop

Comment: Something like.. `while (#featLinkWorkshops).hover { ('#featWorkshops').show(); current.hide()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the jquery cycle plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

> 1- you can go here to see how to generate thumbnails :
>   http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html
>
> 2- and here to see how to generate captions :
>   http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html

combining those two together will take care of the sildeshow part the rest is a matter of css styles.

Comment: I have tried the jQuery cycle plugin. Two problems came up with it: 1)captions need to be styled distinctly (with a header and some interesting text) and can't be added into the alt tags of the images to preserve their style. 2) jQuery cycle also doesn't give a conveinent way to have the image appear on hover AND transition to a another page, rather than the image itself, on click.

Comment: @Stevie - only the text is written in the alt tag but the caption itself is shown in an element of you choice like a div which you can easily add styles to it via css. as for the hover effect you can make jquery click on the button when the user hover over it.

Comment: The alt tag needs to be styled with both <h1> and <p> tags, is that possible through cycle? And w/ the hover effect, can you have jQuery click on the button and not cause it to activate the link to send the user to the next page?

Comment: @Stevie - you can use the img alt tag for the <p> text and the img title tag for the <h1> text. as for the second part do you need the thumbnails to act as links to other pages.

Comment: That's a handy solution to the first problem! And as for the 2nd, I need the thumbs to do two things: on hover, display a new large image and on click take you to another page.

Comment: @Stevie - that is very easy all you have to do is change the pagerEvent to mouse over see this example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager5.html

Comment: @Stevie - as for the clickable thumbnails refer to this example : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pagerHover2.html

Comment: @Whatever - thanks! I suppose next time I should explore the functionality of cycle more!